# Problem with MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to debug a MySQL query, and I have trouble understanding why one while loop in my script is not working:

```
// select db
mysql_select_db($dbname);

for ( $x = $latRange[0]; $x <= $latRange[1]; $x++ )
{

   for ( $y = $lngRange[0]; $y <= $lngRange[1]; $y++)
   {
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE $xlookup = $x AND $ylookup = $y";

  $SQLresult = mysql_query($sql);

  while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($SQLresult) )    
    {       
       $tmpResult = $row[$popDen];                  
                     $result += $tmpResult;   
    }


 }

}
```

Sample values of the variables described are:

```
 $latRange = array(3,7);
 $lngRange = array(9,25);
 $popDen = 'ColumnNameIWant'
 $xlookup = 'Col1'
 $xlookup = 'Col2'
```

The logic behind my query is that it finds all combinations of `x` and `y`, gets the corresponding `$popDen` value, and adds it to `$result`. Result is defined at the start of my script, and returned by the program after this loop.

I know that the problem section is my while loop, but I don't quite understand how to fix it as I don't fully understand how `mysql_fetch_array` functions. I've also tried `mysql_fetch_row` and my query does not work with this either.

I know from commenting out various chunks of the code, and passing back other numbers that everything else works; it is just this chunk that is failing.

Are there any obvious errors that I am making?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're doing with the $popDen variable? Also i would use a for each syntax for the final loop as that seems to mimick what you expect better.

Comment: The $popDen contains a string which is a column name. I'm only expecting one value to be returned; I'm new to the syntax and not sure what is best to use.

Comment: Are $xlookup and $ylookup defined anywhere? You're not checking if the query call succeeded at all. If it's bad, then the rest of the code will blow up as well. do at least `mysql_query(..) or die(mysql_error())` as a stopgap debugging method.

Comment: Yes they are defined ( I just updated my question) - I'm trying mysql_query( " query" ) now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `popDen` is a column in your table, you need to get it with:

```
$tmpResult = $row['popDen'];
```

and if it is the only value you need, you can simplify / speed up your sql query:

```
$sql="SELECT `popDen` FROM $usertable WHERE $xlookup = $i AND $ylookup = $y";
```

**Edit:** By the way, you might want to initialize your `$result` variable so that it has a defined / valid / known value if no rows are found.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - that helped me neaten my code and solve my problem. I had initialized $result, but I was mangling it so badly the script was failing.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious error is to use dynamic table names.
This leaves hard to close SQL-injection holes:

Use this code to plug that hole, because `mysql-real_escape_string()` will not help!

```
$allowed_tables = array('table1', 'table2');
$clas = $_POST['clas'];
if (in_array($clas, $allowed_tables)) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `$clas`";
}
```

See here for more info: [How to prevent SQL injection with dynamic tablenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811834/why-would-this-be-poor-php-code/5811853#5811853)
And don't forget to always enclose dynamic tablenames in backticks `` ` `` or your code will break if you happen to use a reserved word or a number for a table or column name.