# How can I prevent SQL injection with dynamic tablenames?

Tags: php, sql-injection

I had this discussion with a high reputation [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) guy:

> [PDO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#History) has no use here. as well as mysql_real_escape_string.
>   extremely poor quality.

This of course is cool, but I honestly don't know what's wrong with suggesting use of `mysql_real_escape_string` or PDO to fix this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var layer;

    window.location.href = "example3.php?layer="+ layer;

    <?php
        //Make a MySQL connection
        $query = "SELECT Category, COUNT(BUSNAME)
          FROM ".$_GET['layer']." GROUP BY Category";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Into this

```
$layer = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['layer']);
$query = "SELECT Category, COUNT(BUSNAME)
FROM `".$layer."` GROUP BY Category";
```

, considering that the [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) code gets send client-side.

Comment: Can someone please post sample code how to fix this SQL-injection hole?

Comment: @nikic I see where you're going, but it does not look foolproof :-)

Comment: Yeah, I don't think it's foolproof either. The problem I see is this encoding related stuff, as I mentioned in my answer below. But I have no idea how these encoding based hacks work and thus don't know, how to prevent them.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Your advice is indeed incorrect.

`mysql_real_escape_string()` will not work for dynamic table names; it is designed to escape *string data, delimited by quotes*, only. It will not escape the backtick character. It's a small but crucial distinction.

So I could insert a SQL injection in this, I would just have to use a closing backtick.

PDO [does not provide sanitation for dynamic table names, either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622521/which-tokens-can-be-parameterized-in-pdo-prepared-statements).

This is why it is good not to use dynamic table names, or if one has to, comparing them against a list of valid values, like a list of tables from a `SHOW TABLES` command.

I wasn't really fully aware of this either, and probably guilty of repeating the same bad advice, until it was pointed out to me here on SO, also by Col. Shrapnel.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer.  I certainly leaned something new today!

Comment: +1 This is something I have for long time missed in PDO. A `PDO->quote(..., PDO::PARAM_IDENTIFIER)` or something like that. This often diminished PDOs cross-DB approach, because different DBs have different quotation and escaping for that. In MySQL you most oftenly use the backtick and `"` is only an identifier quote in `ANSI` mode, but in other DBMS on the other hand `"` is the way to go. Hum, hum, hum :)

Comment: @nikic yeah! This is definitely a shortcoming of PDO. I don't understand it either.

Comment: +1 for the SHOW TABLES... You can cache the result to avoid calling it each time.

Answer (score 5):

For the record, here's sample code for fixing this hole.

```
$allowed_tables = array('table1', 'table2');
$clas = $_POST['clas'];
if (in_array($clas, $allowed_tables)) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `$clas`";
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 2):

In order to answer how to actually fix the code:

```
'...FROM `' . str_replace('`', '``', $tableName) . '`...'
```

This duplicates all backticks in the table name (this is how escaping in MySQL is done).

One thing I'm not sure about, is whether this is "encoding-safe" (how does one call it correctly?). One typically recommends `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of `addslashes`, because the former takes the encoding of the MySQL connection into account. Maybe this problem applies here, too.

Comment: @nikic, this will not prevent using `table\`\` union select x,y from mysql.user` as a tablename

Comment: @Johan: Why not? It will be inserted as: `... FROM \`table\`\`\`\` union select x,y from mysql.user\` ...`

Comment: so leave out the backticks and inject `table&#96; union select x,y from mysql.user`

Comment: @Johan: What is `&#96;` supposed to mean? If that is a HTML entity equivalent to the backtick, then: HTML Entities work just in HTML, not in SQL. In SQL those are just normal characters.

Comment: @nikic, I know you want to pretend your code is secure, but trust me it isn't, depending on the charset/collation of your database connection metachars like the one above will get translated into special chars like backticks. The only way to be secure is to check the tablename/fieldname/columnname against a list of pre-approved names. If you don't believe me, ask @Pekka.

Comment: @Johan: I already wrote in my answer that this approach probably isn't encoding-safe. But I don't know enough about different encodings in order to give you a definite answer here. If the encoding of the database and connection is known to be, say UTF-8, this may indeed be a safe way to do things. If you don't have character set information, then there obviously arise problems ;)