# how list ids in table then use this list to "not in - not exit " for other table?

Tags: sql

I'm doing classified table which have featured ad and normal ad they are mixing up

the web will show latest 4 feature ads order by id
then show other ads include featured ads and normal ads order by id but not have 4 ads which ready been show as before, but I don't what to use nested query

I have difficulty to create the list of id first 4 ads then exclude them on next query..
here's example which I did simplified, I cut out all other conditions for easy understanding.

```
$sql = "SELECT adid,title FROM $t_ads where featured='1'";

$featres = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error().$sql);
```

.. how to create a string list like this
$excludeadid = "1,2,3,5,7";

then

```
$sqlall = "SELECT adid,title FROM $t_ads where adid not in (".$excludeadid.")" ;
```

or may be use not exit ?
or other way to do it right ? best performance

Comment: do you know that `SELECT adid,title FROM $t_ads where featured='1'` is at risk from SQL-injection!!, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811834/why-would-this-be-poor-php-code/5811853#5811853 to see what's the problem.

Comment: also always use mysql_real_escape_string (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain) to see why **and** change this `"SELECT adid,title FROM $t_ads where adid not in (".$excludeadid.")"` (bad) into this `"SELECT adid,title FROM $t_ads where adid not in ('.$excludeadid.')" ` (good)

Answer (score 1):

Why not do:

```
$sql = "SELECT adid,title FROM $t_ads where featured <> '1'";
```

Judging from your code this might be what you want ... Your question has some typos and is difficult to understand, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: no the query i did is only simple one, the fact is more complex and it use other few more table joining, the second query need both featured ads and normal ads .. so i cant exclude featured as you mention.. thanks

Comment: You should post the whole query then

Comment: dear.. i got a solution just do while for puting the id on the list
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($featres)) { $excludeadid .= "'".$row['adid']."',";}
 $excludeadid = trim( $excludeadid,',');
SO i got the showed featured ad's ids
But now i got other issue ...

i can not call the  for second time, this query when i need full detail of the ads
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($featres))
it return blank result  ...  

have you got any idea ?

Comment: At last got solution when searching on php.net
the if we use the call mysql_fetch_array many time.. remember to put the pointer to the fist of array

    mysql_data_seek($featres, 0); // point to fist row, because now it in the last when get id of feature ads.

now free to use mysql_fetch_array other time

Comment: @binh, you you found a solution, don't put it in a comment, but answer your own question, so others can see what you did and learn from that.