# Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given

Tags: php, mysql

It is a simple PHP MySQL search engine,
in which the searching element is "adm_no".

```
<?php 
require_once("lib/connection.php"); 
require_once("lib/functions.php"); 
$adm_no=$_POST['adm_no'];
//if (!$adm_no==ctype_digit) echo "You Entered wrong Admission no Recheack Admission no" ; exit(); 
$clas=$_POST['clas'];
$query="SELECT * FROM $clas WHERE adm_no = $adm_no";
$result = mysql_query($query);
//searchs the query in db.
while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $result)) 
{ 
echo $result['adm_no']; 
echo " "; 
echo $result['adm_dt']; 
echo ""; 
echo $result['name']; 
echo ""; 
echo $result['dob']; 
echo " "; 
echo $result['f_name']; 
echo " "; 
echo $result['f_office']; 
echo " "; 
echo $result['f_o_no']; 
echo " "; 
echo $result['m_name']; 
echo " "; 
echo $result['m_office']; 
echo " "; 
echo $result['addr']; 
echo " "; 
} ;
```

And the error I am getting is

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in C:\wamp\www\st_db_1\search_db.php on line 10

Comment: We're getting fed up with people writing sql injection-vulnerable code too.

Comment: this is really bad code. The SQL injection hole in this code cannot be fixed by using `mysql_real_escape_string()` because you are injecting the tablename into the query, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain And then read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811834/why-would-this-be-poor-php-code

Answer (score 9):

You do realize that `while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $result))` stomps on the existing value of `$result`, right? Use a different variable.

Comment: thank's dude you just solved it but ...when i use $result twice it should flush first $result

Comment: $result is your resource defined outside the loop, and you're overriding it with an array in the loop, therefore it is no longer a resource.

Comment: @Ravi: when you set $result from mysql_query, it's a mysql statement handle. Then you overwrite it in the loop with an array via mysql_fetch. The next time around, it's not longer a statement handle for the fetch call, which is where your error/warning comes from.

Answer (score 4):

Three issues:

1. Where are you calling [`mysql_connect()`](http://us.php.net/mysql_connect)?
2. You're overwriting `$result` in your loop statement.
3. There's a huge SQL-injection hole in your code.

Comment: Re: #1 - It was probably in one of his included/required files.

Answer (score 0):

RAVI you can fix the SQL-injection code by changing this code:

[image]**Coding horror**

```
$adm_no=$_POST['adm_no'];
$clas=$_POST['clas'];
$query="SELECT * FROM $clas WHERE adm_no = $adm_no";
```

to this **approved code**:

```
$allowed_tables = array('table1', 'table2'); //list of allowed tables
$clas = $_POST['clas'];
$adm_no= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adm_no']);
if (in_array($clas, $allowed_tables)) {
    $query="SELECT * FROM `$clas` WHERE adm_no = '$adm_no'";
//                        ^     ^ backticks      ^       ^ single quotes
}
```

Don't forget to add the backticks ` around tablenames.
And even more important don't forget the single quotes `'` around parameters or you will still be vulnerable!

See: [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)
For SQL-injection in general.
And: [How to prevent SQL injection with dynamic tablenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811834/why-would-this-be-poor-php-code)
For SQL-injection problems when using dynamic table or field names.