# Sample code to fix this particular SQL-injection hole

Tags: php, sql-injection

**Please read fully first**

In this answer: [How to prevent SQL injection with dynamic tablenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811834/why-would-this-be-poor-php-code/5811853#5811853)

Pekka points out why this code:

```
$clas=$_POST['clas'];
$query="SELECT * FROM $clas ";
```

Cannot be repaired by using a PDO or `mysql-real_escape_string()`.

Can anyone please provide **sample code** how to fix this so a newbie can paste that code
*(after/adjusting it to his needs)* and be safe from SQL-injection.

*Please don't explain SQL-injection, I know all about injection and PDO, I just need sample code*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a whitelist to ensure that the value is indeed one of the tables you wish to be accessed in that way.

Example:

```
$allowed_tables = array('table1', 'table2');
$clas = $_POST['clas'];
if (in_array($clas, $allowed_tables)) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `$clas`";
}
```

Note that constructing SQL queries *directly* from GET or POST parameters is usually a bad idea anyways,  but a whitelist can make it safe.

Comment: I think Pekka, the accepted answerer in the other thread the OP links, actually suggests this (or rather suggests restricting to a list such as a SHOW TABLE query). So in that respect, this is stricter and virtually Pekka  approved(tm)

Comment: I'd recommend adding backticks ` around the `$clas` just in case a user want to use a reserved word as table name.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the  for escape :P

```
$clas = str_replace('`','\\`',$_POST['clas']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM \`{$clas}\`";
```

So, is a ver very bad idea.

Do it different.

Comment: is safe. check: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html, more explames?: http://pastebin.com/MEUU82nM .. please check before vote!!!