# Not able to echo variables

Tags: php, mysql

Why am I not able to echo those things like `adm_no`, `adm_dt`, etc.?

```
require_once("lib/connection.php");
$adm_no = $_POST['adm_no'];
if (!$adm_no == "intval") echo "You Entered wrong Admission no Recheack Admission no";
exit();
$clas = $_POST['clas'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM $clas WHERE adm_no = $adm_no";
$result = mysql_query($query);
//searchs the query in db.
while ($result1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $adm_no = $result1['adm_no'];
    $adm_dt = $result1['adm_dt'];
    $name = $result1['name'];
    $dob = $result1['dob'];
    $f_name = $result1['f_name'];
    $f_office = $result1['f_office'];
    $f_o_no = $result1['f_o_no'];
    $m_name = $result1['m_name'];
    $m_office = $result1['m_office'];
    $addr = $result1['addr'];
};


echo "Admission no = ";
$adm_no;
echo " <p>Admission Date  </p>";
echo "   <p>Name  </p>";
echo "  <p>Class </p>";
echo "  <p>D.O.B    </p>";
echo "  <p>Father s name    </p>";
echo "  <p>Office address    </p>";
echo "  <p>Office No   </p>";
echo "  <p>Mother s name   </p>";
echo "  <p>Office Address     </p>";
echo "  <p>Address      </p>";
echo "  <p>Phone no   </p>";
```

Comment: What is this: if (!$adm_no=="intval")?

Comment: This needs basic debugging, not the help of a Q&A site. Does the query work out? What does `mysql_error()` say? Do the POST variables get submitted? What error messages do you get? Does the result contain anything? Is the `while` loop executed?

Comment: Please don't add `MANY CAPITALS` in your question's titles and especially **don't** use phrases like “it's urgent!”: that will not make us answer your questions sooner, it's merely annoying.

Comment: **Warning:** possible SQL injection with `$clas` (and possibly with `$adm_no`): always properly escape user input or, better, use parametrized queries! And (thanks to David Dorward below) you should use `htmlspecialchars` when outputting HTML to prevent XSS.

Comment: @Ravi: Look at @Shakti 's answer the problem is using `exit` as a second statement without the `{ }`

Comment: -1 For SQL-injection hole in the code, you have been informed about this issue before in your prior question, that has since been deleted. See my answer below on how to fix this and please don't post SQL-injectable code on SO. Many people will downvote you for that.

Answer (score 4):

You have a syntax error

```
echo "Admission no = " ;$adm_no ;
```

Should be

```
echo "Admission no = " ; 
echo $adm_no ;
```

or

```
echo "Admission no = " . $adm_no ;
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, the following does `print` a string and then does nothing with the variable:

```
echo "Admission no = " ;$adm_no ;
```

You where probably going for:

```
echo "Admission no = " . $adm_no;
```

---

Apart from that, are you aware that the print logic is only evaluated once *after* the `while` loop has iterated all the results (if more than one). That is, the variables will hold the values of the *last* record only.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the problem your `exit();` is executing every time even if the input `$adm_no` is okay.

Change this

```
if (!$adm_no=="intval") 
      echo "You Entered wrong Admission no Recheack Admission no" ;
      exit();
```

to

```
if (!$adm_no=="intval") 
{
      echo "You Entered wrong Admission no Recheack Admission no" ;
      exit(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As I told you in the previous (deleted) question, you have an **SQL-injection** hole.
Here's how to fix it.

Change this code:

[image]**Coding horror**

```
$adm_no = $_POST['adm_no']; 
if (!$adm_no == "intval") 
  echo "You Entered wrong Admission no Recheack Admission no"; 
exit(); 
$clas = $_POST['clas']; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM $clas WHERE adm_no = $adm_no";
```

Into this code, which is not exposed to SQL-injection dangers

```
$adm_no = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adm_no']); 
if (!$adm_no == "intval") { 
  echo "You Entered wrong Admission no Recheack Admission no"; exit(); 
}
$allowed_tables = array('table1', 'table2'); 
$clas = $_POST['clas']; 
if (in_array($clas, $allowed_tables)) 
{     
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `$clas` WHERE adm_no = '$adm_no'";    
}
```

I know that the `If` will only accept integers, but the if in your previous question was commented out, therefor it comes and goes, so always escape your inputs before injecting them into your query!

Note how the `if` in your code does not work because you forgot to enclose the body after the `then` in brackets `{}`, causing the `exit();` to always be executed.

For more info on SQL-injection see: [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)
And for info on why `mysql-real-escape_string` or PDO doesn't work with dynamic table names
see: [How to prevent SQL injection with dynamic tablenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811834/why-would-this-be-poor-php-code/5811853#5811853)
And: [Sample code to fix this particular SQL-injection hole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051125/sample-code-to-fix-this-particular-sql-injection-hole)

**XSS hole**
To fix a possible XSS hole, don't do

[image]**Coding horror**

```
echo "Admission no = ".$adm_no;
```

But do this instead:

```
echo "Admission no = ".htmlspecialchars($adm_no);
```

In your case it seems that $adm_no can only hold an integer, but I don't have the table definition so I cannot be sure of that. It's best to be on the safe side and always escape dynamic output using `htmlspecialchars`.

See: [What are the best practices for avoiding xss attacks in a PHP site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoiding-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site)

Answer (score 2):

Statement 1: `echo "Admission no = " ;`

Statement 2: `$adm_no ;`

You aren't echoing the variables.

You should probably have something like:

```
<p>Admission no = <?php echo htmlspecialchars($adm_no); ?></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The way you assign the variables in the loop doesn't make any sense: if your SQL query returns more than 1 row, your code will simply replace the values. You probably want to echo the results *inside* the loop.
2. There is a syntax error here: `echo "Admission no = " ;$adm_no ;`.. it should be `echo "Admission no = ".$adm_no;`
3. When you are echoing the results, you are not actually echoing the variables: `echo " <p>Admission Date:  $adm_dt </p>";`

Answer (score 0):

Because *echo* accepts parameters as comma-separated list, like

```
echo $one, "two"
```

Using comma is also possible, but better just use heredoc syntax which support variable substitution, if you need to output large chunk of text with newlines

```
echo <<<HEREDOC
Your text with $variables or {$variables} here
with newlines and other nifty plaintext formatting
HEREDOC;
```