# 2nd MySQLi Query causes a "Call to a member function execute() on a non-object"

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a strange problem. There are 2 queries.

```
$sql = "SELECT  `content_auftrag_id` 
        FROM `content` 
        WHERE `content_id` = '".$content_id."' LIMIT 1";
    $ergebnis = $db->prepare( $sql );
    $ergebnis->execute();
    $ergebnis->bind_result( $content_auftrag_vorhanden );

$content_auftrag_id = "test";
$sql = "UPDATE `content` SET `content_auftrag_id` = '".$content_auftrag_id."' 
        WHERE `content_id` = '".$content_id."'";
        $ergebnis2 = $db->prepare( $sql );
        $ergebnis2->execute();
```

When I use them both, then an error occurs for the second one. If I only run the the second, then it works fine. How can it be that both together cause an error?
All variables are there and correct.

Thanks!

Comment: -1, you managed to produce SQL-injectable code by misusing PDO.

Comment: @Johan - Could you please explain how I did it?

Comment: @Johan: based on method names, it was Mysqli, not PDO in use here.  But you're still right.

Comment: @Crayl: you'll want to read through the `bind_param()` method page to gain more insight into how it's done: http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php.  A hint though: often it really doesn't matter if you don't know the variable type when making your `$types` string - "S" generally covers everything anyway, and Mysql will convert it to the appropriate column format on its end.

Comment: @Crayl, you are injecting your $vars into the query by concatenation. However mysqli supports parameters. You should use those instead then you're no longer at risk.

Comment: @Crayl, appreciate it. 95% of [mysql] [php] questions by new users have SQL-injection flaws in them. Even big firms like SONY have SQL-injection holes all over their websites. And it's sooo easy to prevent them. You only need to follow a few basic rules. See e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain and here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5811834/650492

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only work on one prepared query at a time, so to speak.  See [`Mysqli::execute()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) method:

"When using mysqli_stmt_execute(), the mysqli_stmt_fetch() function must be used to fetch the data prior to performing any additional queries."

You can also use the [`store_result()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.store-result.php) method to remove this block as well to perform the next query.

Also, take heed from those who warn you about abusing prepared statements like your example.  Though it works without error if you don't actually have any parameters to bind to, it basically throws sql injection prevention out the window.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I think you didn't quite got the idea behind PreparedStatements. You shouldn't directly insert the parameters in your SQL-String, but use `?`-placeholders and bind them in the Query using the [bind_param()](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)-method.

Your error seams to appear here:

```
$ergebnis2 = $db->prepare( $sql );
```

This function returns `false` if it wasn't successful. You should check if the value of `ergebnis2` is not `false`.

Also, you should use the [error](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php)-method to see the last appeared MySQL-Error.

Answer (score 2):

If $ergebnis2 is 'not an object', then I guess it must be false. Which means the prepare() call failed for whatever reason.

What does $db->error return after you have called the 2nd prepare?
Always check your return values, its basic debugging