# Adding control to a table (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP / MYSQL Add button to column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325281/php-mysql-add-button-to-column)

Please correct any mistakes throughout this question - I am very new to both PHP and MYSQL.

My goal is to create a table, that I will display onto a web page that looks something like this:[image]

I have done the following. Any help on where I go wrong is much appreciated.

1. Created a MYSQL Table named "`CustomerInformation`"
2. Added five columns to the table, identical to the five columns in the picture above; (`id, name, email, is_admin, Action`).
3. I made four `$POST` text boxes whose data will be passed into each column (other than the last one as I want an "action" button to appear there).
4. Below I will show my *full* code for which I used in order to populate a new row in my `CustomerInformation` table.

```
<?php

// Connect to the database
mysql_connect ("localhost","username","password") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
echo "connected to database!";
mysql_select_db ("database");

// Create variables to retrieve the POST data
$ID= $_POST['textbox1'];
$C_ID= $_POST['textbox2'];
$Value= $_POST['textbox3'];
$Count= $_POST['textbox4'];
$action = ' "<input type="submit" name="AddRow" value="Add New Row" />"';

// Insert data into table
$query = "INSERT INTO CustomerInformation (ID,C_ID,Value,Count,Action) 
VALUES(
'".$ID."', '".$C_ID."', '".$Value."', '".$Count."','".$action."')";
mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database');
echo "Database updated successfully!";
?>
```

The only problem occurs when I include the line: `$action = ' "<input type="submit" name="AddRow" value="Add New Row" />"';`

I am clearly butchering this line, and I would greatly appreciate any help at all on this one!

Comment: stop there. don't use mysql_query. use pdo

Comment: yeah, your suggested problem isn't the only problem. you've gotta validate and sanitize, son

Comment: Why do you need to store the action in the database? Edit: @Dave, +1 for "validate and sanitize, son". Word.

Comment: What's wrong with `$action = '<input type="submit" name="AddRow" value="Add New Row" />';`?

Comment: Action should not be a column in the database table. It's just contains buttons for editing, reading and deleting data on this tuple. You will generate these when displaying a row.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is quite simply [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string). Apply it on ***each*** string variable before you intermingle it with the SQL command.

It's simpler however not to bother with the old mysql_ API. You can keep the query separate from the data and avoid the effort with:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=db', 'username', 'pwd');

$db->prepare(" INSERT INTO CustomerInformation 
               (ID,C_ID,Value,Count,Action) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) ")
   ->execute(array($ID, $C_ID, $Value, $Count, $action));
```

Comment: No, the answer is to use a better DB library that prevents you from shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: That's an interesting thought, but not much of an explanation.