# Unknown column 'date_added' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I am attempting a LOAD DATA INFILE and getting the above error.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '$file'
REPLACE INTO TABLE $custom_parts
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
 (`partsno`, `mfg`, `cond`, `price`, `is_deleted`, @date_added)
   SET `date_added` = STR_TO_DATE(@date_added, '%c/%e/%Y'),
  `prtky` = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(partsno, ' ', '' ) 
   , '\\\\', '' ) , '/', '' ) , '_', '' ) , '.', '' ) , '-', '' )
```

The columns of the file are so

```
Part Number,MFR,Condition,price,is_deleted,date_added
```

Whenever I run the PHP to load this, I get the error.  I am entrigued as why this is occuring.  I believe that it is an issue with the user variable not being assigned and I am just looking for verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question. ---- User variables may be used in most contexts where expressions are permitted. This does not currently include contexts that explicitly require a literal value, such as in the LIMIT clause of a SELECT statement, or the IGNORE N LINES clause of a LOAD DATA statement.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use variables for dynamic table names.
You can only do this using prepared statements,

**However**
You cannot use `load data infile` inside a stored procedure and I'm not sure you can use it in a prepared statement either.

If you use MySQL from a higher level program (php, pascal, whatever) you can

1. resolve the variable before constructing the query;
2. Check the columnname against a whitelist to prevent SQL-injection
3. Feed MySQL the expanded statement.

See this question for sample code: [How to prevent SQL injection with dynamic tablenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811834/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-with-dynamic-tablenames)

Also, if you are using dynamic tablenames, escape them using `` ` `` backticks. This prevents MySQL from bombing if the tablenames contains funny chars or is a reserved word.

Comment: Table isn't dynamic.  This is a prepared statement in a PHP file.  The statement works just fine if I claim the column away from the user variable, but I need the variable for the str_to_date portion, and per mysql is is possible http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: I answered my own question. ---- User variables may be used in most contexts where expressions are permitted. This does not currently include contexts that explicitly require a literal value, such as in the LIMIT clause of a SELECT statement, or the IGNORE N LINES clause of a LOAD DATA statement.

Comment: @Johan _You cannot use variables for dynamic table names.
You can only do this using prepared statements,_  -- I'm not sure I agree with this.  Using prepared statements, you cannot use a placeholder as a tablename nor bind a value to it.  You can use a variable to represent a dynamic tablename.   Is this what you mean to say?