# PHP function problem

Tags: php, mysql

My PHP function for sidebar element generation looks like that

```
function makeSidebarEl ($side, $name, $lang, $db)
{
    $title='title_'.$lang;
    $txt='txt_'.$lang;
    $query=$db->query("SELECT $title, $txt FROM sidebar WHERE side='$side' AND name='$name'");
    $result=$query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    $title=makeTitle($result[$title], $lang, $db);
    $txt=makeTxt($result[$txt], $lang, $db);
    echo '<div class="nav">'.$title.$txt.'</div>'."\n";
    }
```

But i'm getting result something like this

```
<div class="nav"></div>
<div class="nav_1"><img border="0" src=core/design/img/left_nav.png alt="" height="25px"/></div>
...
```

I mean it opens and closes `<div class="nav"></div>` at the begining of the every element but in fact function must echo result within this div:

`echo '<div class="nav">'.$title.$text.'</div>'."\n";` How to fix that problem?

**UPDATE**

```
function makeTitle($title) {

    echo '<div class="nav_1"><img border="0" src=core/design/img/left_nav.png alt="" height="25px"/></div>
    <div class="nav_2">'.$title.'</div>
    <div class="nav_3"><img border="0" src=core/design/img/left_nav.png alt="" height="25px"/></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>';

    }

function makeTxt($txt) {
    echo '<div id="parts" class="parts_txt">'.$txt.'</div>';
}
```

Comment: Dynamic table names, bad bad idea. This is an SQL-injection nightmare and no amount of escaping is going to help you. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811834/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-with-dynamic-tablenames

Comment: Can you show us your `makeTitle()` and `makeTxt()` functions? Also, replace `$text` with `$txt` at the last line.

Comment: Lol I happen to know that high rep guy from that question %)

Comment: it's typo. problem still occurs

Comment: @Johan first i wanna get it work, then i'll think about security

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu, that's the wrong order of doing things. After it works, you will forget about the security. Security is not something you can bold on later. It needs to be included from the start.

Comment: well, what do you suggest to do? I can't find different way to realize my idea

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu, keep the idea, but check the input against a whitelist of allowed tablenames, but like in the linked question. It's really not complicated code, just an extra test against a pre-defined array. See the answers to the linked question for example code.

Comment: wl is the great idea. +1. thx mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`makeTitle()` and `makeText()` should `return` strings rather than `echo` them.

As it is now, they `echo` text when they are called and return `NULL`, which is then concatenated into string when you call `echo '<div class="nav">'.$title.$txt.'</div>'."\n";`, i.e., that line evaluates to `echo '<div class="nav">'.NULL.NULL.'</div>'."\n";`

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `echo` to `return` at functions `makeTitle` and `makeTxt`