# Generate Create Table Script MySQL Dynamically with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, code-generation

I do not think that this has been posted before - as this is a very specific problem.

I have a script that generates a "create table" script with a custom number of columns with custom types and names.

Here is a sample that should give you enough to work from -

```
$cols = array();
$count = 1;
$numcols = $_POST['cols'];
while ($numcols > 0) {

    $cols[] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$count."_name"])." ".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$count."_type"]);
    $count ++;
    $numcols --;
}
$allcols = null;
$newcounter = $_POST['cols'];
foreach ($cols as $col) { 
    if ($newcounter > 1)
        $allcols = $allcols.$col.",\n";
    else
        $allcols = $allcols.$col."\n";
    $newcounter --;
};
$fullname = $_SESSION['user_id']."_".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$dbname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$query = "CREATE TABLE ".$fullname." (\n".$allcols." )";
mysql_query($query);
echo create_table($query, $fullname, $dbname, $actualcols);
```

But for some reason, when I run this query, it returns a syntax error in MySQL. This is probably to do with line breaks, but I can't figure it out. HELP!

Comment: Which part returns the error? What was the error? Did you debug `echo $query;`? Post these things with your question and you'll receive better help.

Comment: If you feel like the line breaks are a problem why don't you remove them?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` doesn't work with dynamic table/column names. See this question on how to make this code secure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811834/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-with-dynamic-tablenames

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have multiple SQL-injection holes**
`mysql_real_escape_string()` only works for values, not for anything else.
Also you are using it wrong, you need to quote your values aka parameters in single quotes.

```
$normal_query = "SELECT col1 FROM table1 WHERE col2 = '$escaped_var' ";
```

If you don't `mysql_real_escape_string()` will not work and you will get syntax errors as a bonus.
In a `CREATE` statement there are no parameters, so escaping makes no sense and serves no purpose.

You need to whitelist your column names because this code does **absolutely nothing** to protect you.

**Coding horror**

```
$dbname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']); //unsafe
```

see this question for answers:
[How to prevent SQL injection with dynamic tablenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811834/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-with-dynamic-tablenames)

**Never use `\n` in a query**
Use separate the elements using spaces. MySQL is perfectly happy to accept your query as one long string.
If you want to pretty-print your query, use two spaces in place of `\n` and replace a double space by a linebreak in the code that displays the query on the screen.

**More SQL-injection**
`$SESSION['user_id']` is not secure, you suggest you convert that into an integer and then feed it into the query. Because you cannot check it against a whitelist and escaping tablenames is pointless.

```
$safesession_id = intval($SESSION['user_id']);
```

**Surround all table and column names in backticks `` ` ``**
This is not needed for handwritten code, but for autogenerated code it is essential.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_18993` (`id` INTEGER .....
```

**Learn from the master**
You can generate the create statement of a table in MySQL using the following MySQL query:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tblname;
```

Your code needs to replicate the output of this statement exactly.