# How to make an SQL query using variable column names?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making a query like this:

```
$b1 = $_REQUEST['code'].'A'; //letter 'A' is concatenated to $_REQUEST['code']
$a = $_REQUEST['num'];
echo $b1.$a;
$sql = "SELECT '".$b1."' FROM student_record1 WHERE id=".$a;
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$result)
{
    echo '<p id="signup">Something went wrong.</p>';
}
else
{
    $str = $row[0]
    echo $str;
}
```

Here `$b1` and `$a` are getting values from another page. The 'echo' in the third line is giving a correct result. And I am not getting any error in SQL. Instead, I am not getting any result from the SQL query. I mean echo at the last line.

Comment: Have you tried outputting what `$sql` contains?  Also, see above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do this, it breaks your relational model and is unsafe.

Instead of having a table with columns `ID`, `columnA`, `columnB`, `columnC`, `columnD`, `columnE` and having the user select `A/B/C/D/E` which then picks the column, have a table with three columns `ID`, `TYPE`, `column` and have `TYPE` be `A/B/C/D/E`. This also makes it easier to add `F/G/H/I` afterwards without modifying the table.

Secondly, with the extra column approach you don't have to build your SQL from input values like that. You can use prepared statements, and be safe from SQL Injection. Building SQL from unfiltered strings is wrong, and very dangerous. It *will* get your site hacked.

Comment: A rare guest on this site - a sensible answer.

Comment: A much more robust solution. +1 to you sir or madam

Comment: okk... thank u... actually i am not greately aware of this sql injections... can u suggest me some good source to steady them...

Comment: @yaswanthchilukuri: You should start by reading what SQL Injection is, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is good enough for that. Only after you understand how the vulnerability manifests, you can start protecting yourself from it. Use the libraries that exist, don't invent your own (it will fail). Since you seem to be using PHP, you will be using [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: Thanks, that means a lot, coming from you.

Comment: a funny enough, no mysql_real_escape_string nor prepared statements could help with field names

Comment: @yaswanth I've covered the whole matter in these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-insert-statement and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-insert-statement

Comment: I agree it does not help with field names, but since I don't think the field names solution is a good one, I proposed an alternative. If you must use field names, a whitelist is the best option.

Answer (score 2):

If you must use dynamic table/column/database names, you'll have to run them through a whitelist.

The following code will do:

```
$allowed_column = array('col1', 'col2'); 
$col = $_POST['col']; 
if (in_array($col, $allowed_column)) { 
    $query = "SELECT `$col` FROM table1 "; 
}
```

See: [How to prevent SQL injection with dynamic tablenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811834/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-with-dynamic-tablenames)

For more details.