# How to run this mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am trying to load all records from the database that have been created by the current logged on user in Joomla, im not sure if its possible to have php inside a mysql query though ?, if not how would I go about doing this otherwise ?

```
SELECT
  leadname,
  businessname,
  postcode,
  gasoiluser,
  dervuser,
  kerouser,
  cf_uid,
  cf_id
FROM
  #__chronoforms_data_addupdatelead
WHERE createdby = '<?php
  $user =& JFactory::getUser(); echo $user->get('name') ; ?>'
ORDER BY cf_created DESC
```

Comment: How are you trying to run this?

Comment: uh? what prevents you from using a variable and placing it inside the query? Is this inside Joomla, right?

Comment: when I run this I get 'no data found', even though there are records that are created by the logged in user

Comment: please provide more context. do you use this query inside a php file? how do you run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can access PHP variables for creating the query - as the `#__` prefix suggests, you're already running your query from "inside Joomla". Which means it **is** in php, and something like this should do what you want:

```
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
if (!$user->guest) {
    $query = 'SELECT leadname, businessname, postcode, gasoiluser, '.
        ' dervuser, kerouser, cf_uid, cf_id '.
        ' FROM #__chronoforms_data_addupdatelead '.
        ' WHERE createdby = '.$db->Quote($user->name)).
        ' ORDER BY cf_created DESC';
    $db->setQuery($query);
}
```

But a little more context would help us see what you'll have to do exactly - what's the code around the SQL query - is it in a php file?

Remember, `echo` prints to the **Response**, which is not what you want to do in this case, you want to change the query; so just concatenate the variable content to your query, as shown above; and you should actually be already be in php mode where this query is defined, so the `<?php` tag is of no use (but again, too few context to be sure about this)!

Comment: -1 for putting an SQL-injectable `get` in an [php] + [sql] answer. At 1k+ rep you should know better.

Comment: As @Johan correctly pointed out, setQuery() doesn't escape the parameters, but justs returns the query string (substituting/adding the #__ when needed). Although, I must say, the $user->get('name') shouldn't be a problem, unless the user really is the infamous little Bobby :)..Joking aside, that value should already be safe since already treated somewhere else, but I'm not 100% sure about that. IIRC, Joomla has the $db->escape($value) or something similar

Comment: +1, Your answer is absolutely ok, just one note: in Joomla, the proper way to 'escape' variables is using $db->Quote( $xxx ) for values and $db->nameQuote( 'xxx' ) for names (table names, field names..).

Comment: @alghimo, your comment is incorrect (I could say clueless, but that would be rude). Quote does not escape anything, it merely puts `'` quotes around it, table, column and field names cannot be escaped, they need to be whitelisted. If you don't Bobby Tables will get you.

Comment: Hi Johan. $db->Quote automatically calls $db->getEscaped (in Joomla 1.5) or $db->escape (in Joomla 1.7, I don't know which one gets called in Joomla 1.6), unless you set the second parameter to false. Besides, getEscaped has deprecated in Joomla 1.7. Many thanks for your comment, it has make me check again something I had for sure and that's always good :) I've also seen that $db->escape has a second parameter to add "extra" escaping (in the case of MySQL db, it calls addcslashes after calling mysql_real_escape_string. If you want to use that, then it's better to use $db->escape

Comment: @alghimo, I'm beginning to like Joomla, it does seem to get a lot of things right. Note that field/column etc names still need to be whitelisted. They cannot be escaped by any means, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811834/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-with-dynamic-tablenames

Answer (score -1):

mysql is a database server that accepts a *string* and returns either *result set* or an *error*

*string* passed to mysql must be proper SQL statement

what you have in your question is not proper SQL statement, it is a string waiting to be parsed by PHP and whoever knows by who else

this part is PHP for sure:

```
<?php $user =& JFactory::getUser(); echo $user->get('name') ; ?>
```

this part is something like a placeholder for correct table name that is replaced at runtime of whatever you got this query from(supposedly joomla):

```
#__chronoforms_data_addupdatelead
```

if you want to run that query you must to figure out what to substitute with the aforementioned blocks

Comment: question was if it's possible to have php inside mysql query and i guess i answered that